# Example for Bubbling and Capturing in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I am looking for an example in handling Bubbling and Capturing in React.js. I found [one with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing), but I am having trouble finding the equivalent for React.js.

How would I have to create an example for Bubbling and Capturing in React.js?

Comment: event bubbling is a DOM specific event concept. The whole point of React is to get away from the DOM. You would do this in React by creating component functions and passing them down to children via props

Comment: Look at [React events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) and [React DOM event listeners](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Bubbling and capturing are both supported by React in the same way as described by the DOM spec, except for how you go about attaching handlers.

Bubbling is as straightforward as with the normal DOM API; simply attach a handler to an eventual parent of an element, and any events triggered on that element will bubble to the parent as long as it's not stopped via `stopPropagation` along the way:

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick}>
  <button>Click me, and my parent's `onClick` will fire!</button>
</div>
```

Capturing is just as straightforward, though it's [mentioned only briefly in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#supported-events). Simply add `Capture` to the event handler property name. For example `onClick` becomes `onClickCapture`:

```
<div onClickCapture={this.handleClickViaCapturing}>
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
    Click me, and my parent's `onClickCapture` will fire *first*!
  </button>
</div>
```

In this case, if `handleClickViaCapturing` calls `stopPropagation` on the event, the button's `onClick` handler will not be called.

[This JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hilome/edit?js,output) should demonstrate how capturing, bubbling, and `stopPropagation` works in React: https://jsbin.com/hilome/edit?js,output

Comment: What is to keep in mind, all vanilla javascript events, for example from a library, are called beforehand. No matter if you register the event on Capture or Bubble phase.

Comment: What if I want the opposite ? What if I am having the `onClick` for the parent and I want to call that function even when child is clicked ?

Comment: @Dane That is normal event bubbling, as described in the first of the two examples above (the parent div's onClick is triggered when you click on the child button).

Comment: @MichelleTilley. Can you please help me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690686/capture-event-of-children-in-parent-component-react-with-no-markup-of-own

Comment: @Jodo that's very relevant - I've just extended your JSBin to reflect that https://jsbin.com/zuleceg/1/

Comment: What about with keydown? @MichelleTilley

Comment: @Pants What about it? If you have a specific question that can't be answered in a small comment, please ask a separate SO question.

Comment: What are the use cases for capture phase event handlers?