# Why does Checkbox fires Tabs onChange event in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) for React.

I have a checkbox inside of a tab:

```
const Layout = () => (
<Tabs value='a' onChange={e => console.log(e)}>
  <Tab label='a' value='a'>
    <Checkbox />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
);
```

When I click on the checkbox `Tabs`' `onChange` event gets fired. Is it intentional behavior? Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is an example: https://github.com/evgeny-t/material-ui-webpack-example/compare/master...evgeny-t:checkbox-inside-tabs?expand=1

Comment: Do you have any jsbin or codepen with that? It does not sounds as a normal behavior.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis I've updated the question. The branch contains some irrelevant changes though.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be intentional behaviour. I was able to check and uncheck the Checkbox without firing the onChange of the Tab with the following code:

```
handleChangeCapture(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
checkUncheck(e) {
    console.log('change')
    this.setState({
        isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <Tabs value='a' onChange={ e => console.log(e) }>
                <Tab label='a' value='a'>
                    <div onChangeCapture={this.handleChangeCapture}>
                        <Checkbox onClick={this.checkUncheck} checked={this.state.isChecked}/>
                    </div>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Of course, I added `isChecked: false` to the state and put in the constructor      `this.checkUncheck = this.checkUncheck.bind(this);`. Using `onChangeCapture` on a parent div and stopping the propagation of the event (with `stopPropagation`) is basically what I did. [This answer explains how onClickCapture works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34523743/6499571). I didn't explicitly find onChangeCapture in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#supported-events) but it seems to work similarly.