# React onClick event call sequence in embed component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick

```
var mark = null;
class Demo extends React.Component {
  handleClick(evt) {
    mark = "outer";
  }
  handleSpanClick(evt) {
    mark = "inner";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
        <span onClick={this.handleSpanClick.bind(this)}>
          inner
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For example, I expect that the mark will be "inner" when I click span, but actually, the mark will be "outer". I know the onClick event of span will be called firstly, so I cant get "inner".

How can I get "inner" in this sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example for Bubbling and Capturing in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522931/example-for-bubbling-and-capturing-in-react-js)

> Bubbling and capturing are both supported by React in the same way as
>   described by the DOM spec, except for how you go about attaching
>   handlers.

```
<div onClickCapture={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
...
```

Comment: Amazing! I don't even know onClickCapture event, Thank you :)
But I have no way to give you a "UP" because of my reputation, sorry :(

Comment: @wumou.4wei . It's okay, I didn't know this before I answer this question, so get the skill together.