# Will react "capture" event handlers always trigger before native non-capture handlers?

Tags: reactjs, dom, event-bubbling, event-capturing

In [this Discuss thread](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/ordering-of-native-and-react-events/829/2), [Sophie Alpert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49485/ben-alpert) says this about event handling in React:

> We don't guarantee anything about event ordering between React events and native events.

However, I'm curious if it's safe to assume that React "capture" events, such as `onClickCapture` will always trigger *before* any native non-capture events.

For example, can I assume that a click on the React-rendered div in `MyComponent` will always log "Clicked the div" before it logs "Clicked the window"?

```
window.document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Clicked the window');
}

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div onClickCapture={() => console.log('Clicked the div')}>
    A Div
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I just found this comment which seems to indicate that the answer is "no": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522931/example-for-bubbling-and-capturing-in-react-js#comment75059987_34523743