# In React, why does an onclick event listener on an outer element execute before an inner element's onclick event listener when using addEventListener?

Tags: reactjs, dom-events

I'm trying to understand the order in which events are being executed in a React application. Given the following sample component, why would I be observing `"OUTER ELEMENT"` logged before `"INNER ELEMENT"` when I click on the **inner** `div` element?

I can see that the event is in the bubbling phase, so my understanding is that it should propagate from the target element upwards, but I am observing the opposite happen.

Is my understanding incorrect?

```
export const Test = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const currentRef = ref.current;

        if (!currentRef) {
            return;
        }

        const handler = (e) => {
            console.log("OUTER ELEMENT");
        };

        currentRef.addEventListener("click", handler);

        return () => {
            currentRef.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        };
    });

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            <div
                onClick={(event) => {
                    console.log("INNER ELEMENT");
                }}
            >
                INNER
            </div>
            OUTER
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses a [synthetic event](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-onclick-event-handlers-guide/#what-synthetic-events-react) system to fix some browser inconsistencies in event handling. (See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42327331/25507).)

At the implementation level, it's my understanding that React is actually attaching a single top-level handler for each event (to `document` or the React root or similar) and then dispatching that event through the React tree to the appropriate `onFoo` handler.

As a result, you can't make assumptions about the order of execution between React events and native JS events, and using functions like `Event.stopPropagation` from React to influence JS may not work as expected. (Former React manager Sophie Alpert [said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45537052/25507), "We don't guarantee anything about event ordering between React events and native events.")

Comment: Thank you for this and the links to relevant info, it makes sense to me now. I guess the main takeaway from this is to avoid using DOM native `Event` methods like `addEventListener` and do everything with synthetic events.