# React keydown event capturing and bubbling

Tags: reactjs, events

I want to capture keydown events from children. Is this possible?
So say I have

```
onKeyDown = e => {
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log("Hello world from Parent!");
 return false;
}

<ParentComponent onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}>
  <div tabIndex='0' id='child'>Focus on me and press a button!</div>
</ParentComponent>
```

I want to print "Hello World" when you press a button while focused on the div child.

I've tried it and doesn't seem to be working, and reading another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34523743/6003161) it seems to work with click handlers as long as `e.stopPropagation()` is used. How come it doesn't work with keydown events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're not actually consuming the passed `onKeyDown` prop in the `ParentComponent`. You'd need to do something with it like so:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div onKeyDown={this.props.onKeyDown}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

[See this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7xygxz?embed=1&file=index.js)

*Per OP's questions in the comments below...*

**Stateless:**

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => (
  <div onKeyDown={props.onKeyDown}>{props.children}</div>
)
```

**In a div:**

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => (
  <div>
    <div onKeyDown={props.onKeyDown}>{props.children}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: What if <ParentComponent> were inside <div> ?

Comment: And what if the child component is stateless?

Comment: @Pants see the additions I made above