# nested lists using map firing multiple onClick event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating a nested lists from a json file.I converted that json file to an array tree. Here I wanted to make a drop down list using that array tree where onSidebarComponent showing the data according to that. I used array mapping and pushed the data into array and showing them.

But whenever I am  clicking the 1st index data it firing a single click event. whenever I am clicking the leaf child node data it firing 3 click events. On the other hand I don't know how to handle dynamically showing and hiding the single list data. I am giving my code and some screenshot for better understand.

here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import data from './data/categories.json'
import { list_to_tree, search_from_tree } from './data/supportFunc'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: "",
      show1: false,
      show2: false,
      show3: false
    }
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    })
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  onNavPressed1(e, i) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("button pressed1")
    console.log(i)
    this.setState({
      show1: i,
      search: ""
    })
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  onNavPressed2(e, i) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("button pressed2")
    console.log(i)
    this.setState({
      show2: i,
    })
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  onNavPressed3(e, i) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("button pressed3")
    console.log(i)
    this.setState({
      show3: i
    })
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  sideBarComponent(listData) {
    if (this.state.search !== "") {
      var clsName = "navbar-nav padd"
    }
    else {
      var clsName = "navbar-nav padd collapse"
    }

    let arr = []
    listData.map((d, i) => {
      let subarr = []
      d.children.map((child, j) => {
        let subChildArr = []
        child.children.map((subChild, k) => {
          subChildArr.push(<li onClick={(e) => this.onNavPressed3(e, "_" + k)} className="nav-item listItem" key={i + "_" + j + "_" + k}>
            {subChild.Name} <span className="float-right"> {subChild.children.length !== 0 ? <i className="fas fa-angle-right"></i> : " "}</span>
          </li>)
        })
        subarr.push(<li onClick={(e) => this.onNavPressed2(e, "_" + j)} className="nav-item listItem" key={i + "_" + j}>
          {child.Name} <span className="float-right"> {child.children.length !== 0 ? <i className="fas fa-angle-right"></i> : " "}</span>
          <ul className={clsName}>{subChildArr}</ul>
        </li>)
      })
      arr.push(<li onClick={(e) => this.onNavPressed1(e, "_" + i)} className="nav-item listItem" key={i}>
        {d.Name} <span className="float-right ">{d.children.length !== 0 ? <i className="fas fa-angle-right"></i> : " "}</span>
        <ul className={clsName}>{subarr}</ul>
      </li>)
    })
    return (<nav className="navbar">
      <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-width">
        {arr}
      </ul>
    </nav>
    )
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  render() {
    var val = this.state.search.toUpperCase()
    var listData = list_to_tree(data)
    var newListData = search_from_tree(listData, val)
    // console.log("listData======")
    // console.log(newListData)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <input type="text"
            name="search"
            className="App-search"
            onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
            value={this.state.search}
            placeholder="Enter Products Category"
          />
        </header>
        <div className="nav-container">
          {this.sideBarComponent(newListData)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: whenever you click a subitem, the click event propagates to parents as well (which have their own onClick too)

Comment: Is there any solution to prevent parents events?

Comment: Yes. Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What's happening?

That behavior is caused by [the event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/4312466). There are two types of event propagation - Event bubbling and Capturing.

**Event bubbling** - triggers the events of the innermost elements firstly and then propagates the events to the outer elements , i.e. **inside -> out**.

**Event capturing** - triggers the events of the outermost elements firstly and then propagates the events to the inner elements, i.e. **out -> inside**.

## Solution:

Depending on your use-case, here we're talking about Event bubbling. So in order to prevent the event propagation to the the parent elements, you have to stop the event's propagation via `e.stopPropagation()` in your nested items `onClick` handler.

I guess it's perfectly fine to invoke `e.stopPropagation()` in your `onNavPressed` handlers.

However, here's a basic example, that illustrate cleaner how to prevent Event Bubbling in React ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39330942/4312466)):

```
class List extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <ListItem onClick={this.handleClick}>Item</li> 
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.onClick();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </li>       
    )
  }
}
```

---

Credits:

1. [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)
2. [React prevent event bubbling in nested components on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619981/react-prevent-event-bubbling-in-nested-components-on-click)
3. [Example for Bubbling and Capturing in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522931/example-for-bubbling-and-capturing-in-react-js)